# USB disk encryption at driver level

Tags: windows, linux, storage, driver

I am trying to implement a simple encrypted file system for all usb storage devices (flash disks) on a specific PC. This is a matter of security and it would assure that flash disks formatted by other PCs cannot be used in this PC and vice versa. The OS of PCs are either Windows XP, 7 or Linux.

Now my question: what is the best approach for this? Where is the best point for implementing such system?

I have read the [IFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463062) documents in MSDN and it seems that miniFilters may be the best way to go. I can implement a miniFilter that attaches to all USB devices and encrypts write operations and decrypts the read operations. But I think that miniFilters cannot change the file-system tables. This means that all files and folders can be read by unathurized PCs and only the file contents will be encrypted.
An alternative would be a custom file-system but it seems much more difficult to implements.

1) Is there any way to insert a software processing layer between file-system data output and USB bus? In this way I can protect the complete disk data, no matter what file-system it uses.

2) Is there any way to manipulate the file-system tables in miniFilter level and make it unreadable for normal systems?

3) What is the best solution for linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a driver which would filter requests on disk level, rather than on file level. In Windows that's possible, but I don't know about Linux.

For a custom filesystem on the device you can use virtual disk components - for Windows there exist several products with different design approaches on the market (including our SolFS and CallbackDisk products) and I believe it's the same for Linux. But custom filesystem probably won't solve your task completely because while it lets you have custom-formatted and encrypted USB device, one still is able to insert FAT- or NTFS-formatted flash card or USB stick and use it.

Comment: After more reading, I am now sure that implementing a custom file-system is not a practical solution for me (plus the problem of forcing the system to only use this file-system for usb devices).

It seems that there exists something called filter driver which can intercept the input data of a device driver. But my reference is for Windows NT and I am not sure if it applies to newer version.

Comment: @Mostafa Filter drivers exist for all newer versions as well, of course. I know of file system filter drivers and you need device-level filter driver, which is also possible on Windows, but as I said, I don't know about linux.

Answer (score 1):

USB disk encryption at driver level...

That can be done on windows NT by using filter driver.Just go through the details how to create a filter driver.also you need to implement an encryption algorithm which will be called at the time of driver loading,also you can check some product documentations like symantec (PDF) based on the pre boot authentication mechenism then you will get a good idea.

also check for Truecrypt it'll help a lot.based on the full disk encryption.

:-) enjoy